# Program that prints specified number of matroshka dolls

Tags: c++, ascii-art

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    // Prompt for and get the number of dolls.
    int numberOfDolls = 0;
    cout << "Number of dolls -> ";
    cin >> numberOfDolls;
    // outer loop for printing the dolls according to the number entered
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDolls; i++) {
       // printing the head of the doll
       cout << setw(numberOfDolls + 4) << "( )\n";
       // inner loop for printing the upper body of the doll
       for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
          // printing the formatted left side of the doll's upper body
          cout << setw(numberOfDolls - j) << "/";
          // printing the middle character working as neck of the doll
          if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
             cout << " - ";
          } else if (j == 0) {
             cout << " : ";
          } else {
             // printing the required number of spaces between the left and right slashes in one line
             for (int k = 0; k <= (2 * (j + 1)); k++) {
                cout << " ";
             }
          }
          // printing the right side of the doll's upper body
          cout << "\\\n";
       }
       // inner loop to print the lower body of the doll
       for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
          // printing the formatted left side of the doll's lower body
          cout << setw(numberOfDolls - (j - 1)) << "\\";
          // printing the required number of spaces between the left and right slashes in one line
          for (int k = 0; k <= (2 * j); k++) {
             cout << " ";
          }
          // printing the right side of the doll's lower body
          cout << "/\n";
       }
       // printing the end character or foot of the doll
       cout << setw(numberOfDolls + 3) << "-\n";
    }
} // end if( menuOption == 2) // menu option to display dolls
```

Hello, I need to rewrite this code to make it more efficient ( lower number of loops ). The code as of now can print dolls when given a number of how many dolls it needs to print and does that without bugs.

output example:

```
Number of dolls -> 4
    ( )
   / - \
    \ /
     -
    ( )
   / : \
  /     \
   \   /
    \ /
     -
    ( )
   / : \
  /     \
 /       \
  \     /
   \   /
    \ /
     -
    ( )
   / : \
  /     \
 /       \
/         \
 \       /
  \     /
   \   /
    \ /
     -
```

Comment: Do you really need to rewrite the code?  Or do you need a review of what's good and bad about the code you've written?  The latter is what we do here, rather than the former.

Comment: There are the loops to print space which can be replaced by appropriate `setw`.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `using namespace std` - it brings a large (and increasing) number of identifiers into the global namespace, increasing chances of unexpected overloading of your own functions.

When reading from an input stream, it's necessary to ensure the read was successful before using the variables which you intend to be assigned.  You can either test the state afterwards:

```
    std::cin >> numberOfDolls;
    if (!std::cin) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

or you could call `std::cin.exceptions()` to cause failures to throw rather than returning.

Instead of interactively asking for input, consider accepting a command-line argument instead.

---

Rather than putting the whole logic in a giant `main()`, we could create a *function* that prints just one doll:

```
void print_doll(std::ostream& os, int indent, int size);
```

Then call it from `main()`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDolls; i++) {
        print_doll(std::cout, numberOfDolls-i, i);
    }
```

That's making it more comprehensible already.

When we implement the `print_doll()` function, we can replace some of the loops that print spaces.  An easy way to get a programmatic number of the same character is the `std::string` constructor that takes a `char` and a number of repetitions, like this:

```
void print_doll(std::ostream& os, int indent, int size)
{
    // the head
    os << std::setw(indent + size) << ' ' << "( )\n";

    // upper body
    for (int j = 0;  j <= size;  ++j) {
        os << std::setw(indent + size - j) << '/'
           << (j ? std::string(2 * j + 3, ' ') : size ? " : " : " - ")
           << "\\\n";
    }

    // lower body
    for (int j = size;  j >= 0;  --j) {
        os << std::setw(indent + size + 1 - j) << '\\'
           << std::string(2 * j + 1, ' ')
           << "/\n";
    }

    // the feet
    os << std::setw(indent + size + 1) << ' ' << "-\n";
}
```

There's still a bit of awkward calculation around the indentation.  What if we made a local function that could position a string centred on a particular column?

```
void print_doll(std::ostream& os, int mid_column, int size)
{
    auto print_mid = [mid_column,&os](std::string_view s) {
        auto const half_len = s.size() / 2;
        os << std::string(mid_column - half_len, ' ')
           << s
           << '\n';
    };

    // the head
    print_mid("( )");

    // neck
    print_mid(size ? "/ : \\" : "/ - \\");

    // body
    ⋮
}
```

---

## Improved program

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_doll(std::ostream& os, std::size_t mid_column, std::size_t size)
{
    auto print_mid = [mid_column,&os](std::string_view s) {
        auto const half_len = s.size() / 2;
        os << std::string(mid_column - half_len, ' ')
           << s
           << '\n';
    };

    // the head
    print_mid("( )");

    // neck; baby (size 0) has a different tie to others 
    print_mid(size ? "/ : \\" : "/ - \\");

    // body
    for (std::size_t j = 0;  j < size;  ++j) {
        print_mid("/" + std::string(2 * j + 5, ' ') + "\\");
    }

    // lower body
    for (std::size_t j = size + 1;  j > 0;  --j) {
        print_mid("\\" + std::string(2 * j - 1, ' ') + "/");
    }

    // the feet
    print_mid(" - ");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::size_t numberOfDolls = 0;
    if (argc > 1 && *argv[1]) {
        char* end;
        numberOfDolls = std::strtoul(argv[1], &end, 0);
        if (*end) {
            std::cerr << "Cannot print " << argv[1] << " dolls.\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    if (!numberOfDolls) {
        std::cout << "Number of dolls -> ";
        std::cin >> numberOfDolls;
        if (!std::cin) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    if (numberOfDolls <= 0 || numberOfDolls > 20) { // arbitrary limit
        std::cerr << "Cannot print " << numberOfDolls << " dolls.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    auto const mid_col = numberOfDolls + 2;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numberOfDolls; ++i) {
        print_doll(std::cout, mid_col, i);
    }
}
```